# GCD of $2$ and $4 + \sqrt{10}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, unique-factorization-domains

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}] = \{a + b \sqrt{10} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and the norm function $N: \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $N(a + b \sqrt{10}) = a^2 - 10b^2$.

I tried to show that greatest common divisor (GCD) of $\{2, 4 + \sqrt{10}\} = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$.

Definition: in a ring $R$, $d$ is the GCD of $\{ a, b \}$, with $a, b \in R$ if

i) $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$

ii) if there's a $c \in R$ such that $c \mid a$ and $c \mid b$, then $c \mid d$.

We have that $1 \mid 2 $ and $1 \mid 4 + \sqrt{10}$ is trivial. Suppose that there is a $u \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ such that $u \mid 2$ and $u \mid 4 + \sqrt{10}$.

From a known fact about norms, $u \mid 4 + \sqrt{10}$ implies that $N(u) \mid N(4 + \sqrt{10})$. Thus $N(u) \mid 6$. The only divisors of 6 in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$ and $\pm 6$ (which equals 1 reducing mod 5).

From a previously proven fact, there is no $u \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ such that $N(u) = \pm 2, \pm 3$. Hence, $N(u) = \pm 1$ and $u$ is invertible. 
Therefore, $u u^{-1} = 1$, implying that $u \mid 1$.

Analogously, if $u \mid 2$, then $u \mid 1$

**Edit:** If $u \mid 2$, then $N(u) \mid N(2)$. The only divisors of 4 in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4$. We know there's no $u \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ with $N(u) = \pm 2$. Assuming that $N(u) = 4$, we have that $4 \equiv -1 (\mod 5)$, so $N(u) = - 1$, whence $u$ is invertible and $u \mid 1$.

Hence, GCD$\{2, 4 + \sqrt{10} \} = 1$.

Is this reasoning correct?

PS: My goal is to show that the GCD$\{2, 4 + \sqrt{10} \} = 1$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of $2$ and $4 + \sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Norm supposed to be non-negative. What is $N(\sqrt{10})$?

Comment: @dEmigOd the term "norm" is being used in the field-theoretic sense from algebra and absolutely can be negative. The norm of $x+y\sqrt{10}$ is $x^2 - 10y^2$.

Comment: The reasoning is mostly okay but sloppy. It is false that "if $u \mid 2$, $u \mid 1$". After all, try $u = 2$. The ideal $(2,4+\sqrt{10})$ is *not* principal and that is causing some problems. Distinguish between gcd as element and gcd as ideal in this ring.

Comment: @Kcd, I've edited part of the answer, for the case when $u \mid 2$. Would that be correct?

Comment: Not at all. Your edit still has problems. You claim that if "$u \mid 2$ then $u \mid 1$" but it makes no sense: just let $u = 2$. You write that if $u$ has norm 4 it has norm $-1$ and that makes no sense. How is the norm value *changing* from 4 to $-1$?? When $u = 2$ its norm is 4 and you can't claim the norm is $-1$.

Comment: @KCd, I tried to reduce modulo 5. Would it be the case that 1 is **not** the gcd of $2$ and $4 + \sqrt{10}$?

Comment: It depends what the term "gcd" means! The only common divisors of $2$ and $4+\sqrt{10}$ in that ring are units, so in the element sense those two numbers are relatively prime. But the ideal those numbers generate, $(2,4+\sqrt{10})$, is not $(1)$. So in the sense of ideals we would say the (principal) ideals $(2)$ and $(4+\sqrt{10})$ are not relatively prime.

Comment: I see, that's precisely what I want to show. Since the greatest common divisor (in terms of elements) is $1$, but the ideal generated by those two elements is not (1), it means that $1$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of $2$ and $4 + \sqrt{10}$. 

Could you provide a hint of what the ideal $(2, 4 + \sqrt{10}$ looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct but can be simplified.

If $u \mid 2$ and $u \mid 4 + \sqrt{10}$, then $N(u) \mid \gcd(N(2),N(4 + \sqrt{10}))=\gcd(4,6)=2$.

Therefore, $N(u)=\pm 1$ or $N(u)=\pm 2$.

You already know that the second case cannot happen, and so $u$ is a unit.